# Magento 2 : Change Product Default Image

Tags: magento2, product, placeholder

I am trying to change the default images on products that haven't got an image.

I've uploaded the images within:

**Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Product Image Placeholders**

I've **flushed my cache and reindexed** and my placeholder image is showing on the category listings but it is still showing the Magento logo default image on the product page?

How can I update this image to my own?

Comment: `Flush Catalog Images Cache` in `system>Cache Storage Management`

Comment: And remove cache in `var\cache` folder

Comment: Hi Ramesh, Thanks for your quick reply :) I've tried the above but still showing the existing image?

Comment: Some info here suggest that this feature might have been removed. some reference:https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203905/magento-2-1-7-no-option-to-change-placeholder-image-in-product-page